# Tweepy still not returning full text despite using extended text feature

Tags: python, mining

I am using tweepy to download tweets about a particular topic but nobody which tutorial I follow I cannot get the tweet to output as a full tweet. There is always an ellipse that cuts it off after a certain number of characters.

Here is the code I am using

```
import json
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler 
import csv
import sys
from twython import Twython
nonBmpMap = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
with open ('Twitter_Credentials.json') as cred_data:
info = json.load(cred_data)
consumer_Key = info['Consumer_Key']
consumer_Secret = info['Consumer_Secret']
access_Key = info['Access_Key']
access_Secret = info['Access_Secret']


maxTweets = int(input('Enter the Number of tweets that you want to extract '))
userTopic = input('What topic do you want to search for ')
topic = ('"' + userTopic + '"')
tweetCount = 0

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_Key, consumer_Secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_Key, access_Secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
tweets = api.search(q=topic, count=maxTweets, tweet_mode= 'extended')

for tweet in tweets:
    tweetCount = (tweetCount+1)
    with open ('TweetsAbout' + userTopic, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as the_File:
        print(tweet.full_text.translate(nonBmpMap))
        tweet = (str(tweet.full_text).translate(nonBmpMap).replace(',','').replace('|','').replace('\n','').replace('â€™','\'').replace('â€¦',"end"))
        the_File.write(tweet + "\n")
        print('Extracted ' + str(tweetCount) + ' tweets about ' + topic)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tweepy: truncated tweets when using tweet\_mode='extended'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966176/tweepy-truncated-tweets-when-using-tweet-mode-extended)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see if it works!

```
try:
    specific_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, tweet_mode='extended', q=<your_query_string> +" -filter:retweets", lang='en').items(500)
except tweepy.error.TweepError:
    pass
for tweet in specific_tweets:
    extracted_text = tweet.full_text
```

all the text your trying to extract should be in `extracted_text`. Good Luck!!